# Strange C++ Memory Allocation

Tags: c++, object, memory, char

I created a simple class, Storer, in C++, playing with memory allocation.  It contains six field variables, all of which are assigned in the constructor:

```
int x;
int y;
int z;
char c;
long l;
double d;
```

I was interested in how these variables were being stored, so I wrote the following code:

```
Storer *s=new Storer(5,4,3,'a',5280,1.5465);
cout<<(long)s<<endl<<endl;
cout<<(long)&(s->x)<<endl;
cout<<(long)&(s->y)<<endl;
cout<<(long)&(s->z)<<endl;
cout<<(long)&(s->c)<<endl;
cout<<(long)&(s->l)<<endl;
cout<<(long)&(s->d)<<endl;
```

I was very interested in the output:

```
33386512

33386512
33386516
33386520
33386524
33386528
33386536
```

Why is the char c taking up four bytes? sizeof(char) returns, of course, 1, so why is the program allocating more memory than it needs?  This is confirmed that too much memory is being allocated with the following code:

```
cout<<sizeof(s->c)<<endl;
cout<<sizeof(Storer)<<endl;
cout<<sizeof(int)+sizeof(int)+sizeof(int)+sizeof(char)+sizeof(long)+sizeof(double)<<endl;
```

which prints:

```
1
32
29
```

confirming that, indeed, 3 bytes are being allocated needlessly.  Can anyone explain to me why this is happening? Thanks.

Comment: It's to do with [alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Data alignment and compiler padding say hi!**

The CPU has no notion of type, what it gets in its 32-bit (or 64-bit, or 128-bit (SSE), or 256-bit (AVX) - let's keep it simple at 32) registers needs to be properly aligned in order to be processed correctly and efficiently. Imagine a simple scenario, where you have a  char, followed by an int. In a 32-bit architecture, that's 1 byte for a char and 4 bytes for an integer.

A 32-bit register would have to break on its boundary, only taking in 3 bytes of the integer and leaving the 4th byte for "a second run". It cannot process the data properly that way, so the compiler will add padding in order to make sure all the stuff is processed efficiently. And that means adding a certain amount of padding depending on the type in question.

### Why is misalignment a problem?

The computer is not human, it can't just pick them out with a pair of eyes and a brain. It has to be very deterministic and cautious about how it goes about doing things. First it loads one block which contains n bytes of the given information, shift it around so that  it prunes out unrelated information, then another, again, shift out a bunch of unnecessary bytes which do not have anything to do with the operation at hand and only then can it do the necessary operations. And usually you have two operands, that's just one complete. When you do all that work, only then can you actually process it. Way too much performance overhead when you can simply align the data properly (and most of the time, compilers do it for you, if you're not doing anything fancy).

### Could you visualize it?

Visually - the first green byte is the mentioned char, and the three green bytes plus the first red one of the second block is the 4-byte int, colorcoded on a 4-byte access boundary (we're talking about a 32-bit register). The "instead part" at the bottom shows an ideal setup where the int hits the register properly (the char getting padded into obedience somewhere off image):

[image]

Read more on data alignment, which comes quite handy when you're dealing with fancy extensions of the instruction set like SSE (128-bit regs) or AVX (256-bit regs), so special care must be taken so that the optimizations of vectorization are not defeated ( aligning on a 16-byte boundary for SSE, 16*8 -> 128-bits).

### Additional remarks on user defined alignment

**phonetagger** made a valid point in the comments that there are pragma directives which can be assigned through the preprocessor to force to compiler in order to align the data in a way the user, programmer specifies. But such directives, like `#pragma pack(...)`, are a statement to the compiler that you know what you're doing and what's best for you. Be sure that you do, because if you fail to accomodate your environment, you might experience various penalties - the most obvious being using external libraries you didn't write yourself which differ in the way they pack data.

Things simply explode when they clash. Best is to advise caution in such cases and really being intimate with the issue at hand. If you're not sure, leave it to the defaults. If you are not sure but have to use something like SSE where alignment is king (and not default nor simple by a long shot), consult various resources online or ask an another question here.

Comment: This is (so far) the best answer.  You're only missing a mention that most compilers support a directive to prevent padding insertions, at the expense of the struct/class data members requiring extra CPU cycles to handle the misaligned access (or perhaps just crashing with a misaligned access exception).

Comment: @phonetagger Good point, it is worth saying that the user/programmer has a say how things are packed, but it does require caution, especially when one is new to the concept.

Answer (score 5):

I will make an analogy to help you understand.

Assume there is a long loaf of bread and you have a cutting machine that can cut it into slices of equal thickness. Then you are giving out these breads to, let's say children. Every child takes their bread and fairly do what they want to do with them (put Nutella on them and eat, etc.). They can even make thinner slices out of it and use it like that.

If one child comes up to you and says that he does not want that slice everyone is getting, but a thinner slice instead, then you will have difficulties, because your cutting machine is optimized to cut at least a minimum amount, which makes everyone happy. But when one child asks for a thinner slice, then you have to reinvent the machine or put additional complexity to it like introducing two cutting modes. You don't want that.  Eventually you give up and just give him a big slice anyway.

This is the same reason why it happens. Hope you could relate to the analogy.

Answer (score 3):

Data alignement is why the char has allocated 4 bytes : [Data alignement](http://www.songho.ca/misc/alignment/dataalign.html)

Answer (score 2):

`char` does not take up four bytes: it takes up a single byte as usual. You can check it by printing `sizeof(char)`. The other three bytes are *padding* that the compiler inserts to optimize access to other members of your class. Depending on hardware, it is often much faster to access multi-byte types, say, 4-byte integers, when they are located at an address divisible by four. A compiler may insert up to three bytes of padding before an int member to align it with a good memory address for faster access.

If you would like to experiment with class layouts, you can use a handy operation called [`offsetof`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstddef/offsetof/). It takes two parameters - the name of the member and the name of the class, and it returns the number of bytes from the base address of your struct to the position of the member in memory.

```
cout << offsetof(Storer, x) << endl;
cout << offsetof(Storer, y) << endl;
cout << offsetof(Storer, z) << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Structure members are aligned in particular ways.  In general, if you want the most compact representation, list the members in decreasing order of size.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Typical_alignment_of_C_structs_on_x86